# Group inside Repeater ACF Pro WordPress Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, repeater, timber, acfpro

I have checked the documentation and various posts and could not find examples of this.
What I want is to access a field of a group, which is within a repeater in ACF Pro, using Timber/Twig.

What I have is:

```
{% for item in post.meta('main_field') %}

{{ item.normal_field }} // outputs fine

{% for group_name in item.main_field %}
{{ group_name.group_field }} // outputs nothing
{% endfor %}

{% for group_name in item %}
{{ group_name.group_field }} // outputs only the first instance
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

If I put `{{ item.group_name.group_field }}` I get only the data from the first item output.

I have also tried adding `{% set group = post.meta('group_name') %}` both before and after `{% for item in post.meta('main_field') %}` which outputs nothing, when referenced by `{{ group.group_field }}`.

So how do you reference a group within a repeater?

Comment: What does `{{ dump( post.meta('main_field') }}` give you?

Comment: Good shout. I had to add a closing comma to the dump statement.
This then threw an error initially:
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "dump" function

I had to add 
```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig\Environment $twig ) {
    if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG
        && class_exists( 'Ajgl\Twig\Extension\BreakpointExtension' )
    ) {
        $twig->addExtension( new Ajgl\Twig\Extension\BreakpointExtension() );
    }

    return $twig;
} );
```

Comment: to functions.php as dump is disabled by default.

Getting the dump output pointed me towards a classic user error. The content of my fields was cleared when moving them inside a group field. Amazing how I failed to actually check the content! 

```
{% for group_name in item %}
{{ group_name.group_field }} 
{% endfor %}
```
works as expected.

Many thanks

Comment: Oop, yeah, sorry, I missed that ")"! I’m glad you got it working!